# Management packages. What tool should I use?

Tags: meteor, package, bower

I'm starting new app with meteor and I'm confuse when I have to install packages.

Meteor gives the possibility to install packages just like that:

`meteor add <username>:<packagename>`

Ok, very easy. The problem is that I would like use bower then, How I have to install the packages? For example angular.

```
meteor add urigo:angular
```

is the same as? what is the difference*? How I have to perform?

```
bower install angular
```

The logical conclusion could be use one of them, but I have seen in examples that they can be toguether.

*the package is recorded in different places, but the operation is the same?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With

```
meteor add <developer>:<packagename>
```

you add packages from the Meteor specific package database. Meteor packages are completely integrated into the Meteor eco-system and may contain both server and client side code.

You should use "meteor add" whenever possible.

To find Meteor packages you can use [Atmosphere](https://atmospherejs.com/)

Bower on the other hand is a framework independent package system for client side (mostly) JavaScript packages. It's not well integrated with Meteor - Although community packages exists to simplify usage of Bower packages with Meteor.

**To answer you specific example:**

```
meteor add urigo:angular
```

This command adds the Angular package of the [Angular-Meteor](http://angular-meteor.com/) project to your Meteor application. It's not only Angular but does also include some Angular services ($meteor) to provide integration of Meteor with Angular.

It even adds Angular support to the server side to some degree.

```
bower install angular
```

only downloads the official minified and non-minified javascript file of the latest Angular version for client side use.
You could use the Bower version with Angular but you wouldn't get the benefits of the integration.

Comment: Clear and concise. Perfect.

Answer (score -1):

While I don't use Bower myself, check out this package: https://atmospherejs.com/mquandalle/bower. I think it may help answer your question.

Comment: I have already installed _bower_ through _meteor_. But what I try to know is the difference (or better option) among install packages with _bower_ or with _meteor_